# Scale a HTML SVG path element and translate the left-top point to the original left-top point using css in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, svg, transform

I created two polygons in svg path data. I would like to scale down the upper layer one, for example with rate 0.4. Then translate the scaled one to the original position which has same left-top point. Here's the pictures to show. 
[This is what I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lsYO.png)
[This is what I did right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H3pd.png)

Right now I can only get the second picture level using jQuery. Anyone can help me? Thank you soooo much!!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 var offsetLeftO = $("#undeveloped:first").offset().left;
 var offsetTopO = $("#undeveloped:first").offset().top;

 $("#developed").css({'transform':'scale(0.4)'});
 var offsetLeft = $("#developed:first").offset().left;
    var offsetTop = $("#developed:first").offset().top;
        
    var offsetX =  offsetLeftO - offsetLeft;
    var offsetY =  offsetTopO - offsetTop;
    
 $("#developed").css({'transform': 'translate('+offsetX+'px, '+offsetY+'px)'+'scale(0.4)'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="170mm"
   height="170mm"
   viewBox="0 0 602.36221 602.36215">
    <path
     style="fill:#00b400;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.93257946px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 307.99025,332.70033 215.2088,-39.40415 -5.50808,198.59689 -190.81585,-1.18212 z"
     id="undeveloped"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  <path
  style="fill:#ff5a00;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.93257946px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 307.99025,332.70033 215.2088,-39.40415 -5.50808,198.59689 -190.81585,-1.18212 z"
     id="developed"
  />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi everyone, my goal is to achieve the match thing automatically whatever the rate is. It means whenever and whatever I enter the rate, the correct svg will show up... And the rate range is 0<= rate <= 1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle. So, the value of offsets is equal to each polygones.

You have to calculate the offset "manualy" to get the good position. Since the top left corner had moved from the square you can't just make the division with the inverse of "0.4" but you have to find the good value.

It's the best I can do but other certainly can improve that answer.

Hope it'll help.

Here is the jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#developed").css({'transform':'scale(0.4)'});
    var offsetLeft = $("#developed:first").offset().left;
    var offsetTop = $("#developed:first").offset().top;


    var offsetX = offsetLeft /1.81;
    var offsetY = offsetTop /1.6;

    $("#developed").css({'transform': 'translate('+offsetX+'px, '+offsetY+'px)'+'scale(0.4)'});
});
```

And the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/f92yx76c/1/

Comment: Thanks for help, but I would like the svg shows up automatically after I type the rate..

Comment: @ValerieRen Do you mean you want to have a text input where you will type the rate, and you want the image to be produced on the fly? But on the original question you seem to want to avoid jQuery?